# Does The Riemann zeta function has a compositional inverse in the strip?

Tags: riemann-zeta, inverse-function

In my question here i search about restriction of some domain or region for which the Riemann zeta function is one to one which means That Riemann zeta function has a compositional inverse then my question here is :

Does Riemann zeta function has a compositional inverse in the strip ?

Comment: If by the strip you mean the one within which we hope all the zeroes lie, then clearly no, since it has multiple zeroes there. Also, being injective only gives a left inverse.

Comment: Thanks , In which region we assure the existence of compositional inverse ?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, any explicit formula for left inverse since it is injective ?